# How can I filter a stream/pipeline to remove headers for empty sections?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

data example from ps aux as followings. There is a newline between each section.

```
com-1
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

com-2
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
testuser   5915  0.0  0.0 108604  2036 pts/0    S+   Jul19   0:00 -bash

com-3
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

com-4
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

com-5
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
tuser2   2531  0.0  0.0 108604  2036 pts/0    S+   Jul19   0:00 -bash
wuser1   3591  0.0  0.0 108604  2036 pts/0    S+   Jul19   0:00 python
```

How to use linux shell pipe to output only the follows? There is no useful infomation for com-1, com-3 and com-4, so only the following is needed.

```
com-2
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
testuser   5915  0.0  0.0 108604  2036 pts/0    S+   Jul19   0:00 -bash

com-5
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
tuser2   2531  0.0  0.0 108604  2036 pts/0    S+   Jul19   0:00 -bash
wuser1   3591  0.0  0.0 108604  2036 pts/0    S+   Jul19   0:00 python
```

Comment: I've tried to edit the title to make it representative of the actual question. In the future, try to be more clear up-front.

Comment: It's going to be tricky: the unix pipeline is built on a heritage of line editors that are extremely powerful for processing streams of text line-wise, but which take some convincing to handle context in a meaningful way. Might be easier to use a little python script instead

Comment: Fix whatever is producing the output.  Run ps with headers suppressed, and only insert the "com-N" headers if any output is produced.  That will be much cleaner than post-processing the output.

Comment: @William Pursell ps aux here is only one example. I actually need to process any shell command to the targeted nodes. Your comment doesn't make too much sense to me. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

headers=( )
headers_printed=0
consecutive_newlines=0

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line ]]; then
    if (( ${#headers[@]} < 2 )); then
      # header not filled out yet, that means we're one.
      headers+=( "$line" )
      continue
    else
      # headers are filled out, and we still have more data
      consecutive_newlines=0
      if (( headers_printed )); then
        # already printed the headers, so just print our one line
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
      else
        printf '%s\n' "${headers[@]}" "$line"
        headers_printed=1
      fi
    fi
  else
    headers=( )
    headers_printed=0
    if (( consecutive_newlines++ == 0 )); then
      printf '\n'
    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, slightly different:

```
#!/bin/sh

# the following is the command to generate the output to filter
command="cat file.txt"       # file.txt contains your example data

# this is the filter - will be used later on
filter () {
while true; do
    read
    [ -z "$REPLY" ] && break;
    machine="$REPLY"
    read
    header="$REPLY"
    first=1
    while true; do
      read
      if [ ! -z "$REPLY" ]; then
        if [ $first -eq 1 ]; then
          echo $machine
          echo $header
          first=0
        fi
      else
        [ $first -eq 0 ] && echo $REPLY
        break
      fi
      echo $REPLY
    done
  done
}

# invoke the command, passing its output to the filter
$command | filter
```

**EDIT**: after being whipped by Charles, and feeling a *little* less lazy today, I post a revised version, which takes in account *some* of the points:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the following is the command to generate the output to filter
command="cat file.txt"       # file.txt contains your example data

# this is the filter - will be used later on
filter () {
while true; do
    read machine || break
    read header
    first=1
    while true; do
      read
      if [ -z "$REPLY" ]; then
        [ $first -eq 0 ] && echo "$REPLY"
        break
      fi

      if [ $first -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "$machine"
        echo "$header"
        first=0
      fi
      echo $REPLY
    done
  done
}

# invoke the command, passing its output to the filter
$command | filter
```

Comment: FYI, `REPLY` being the default destination is a bashism; to be portable to other shells, *always* provide a destination variable name (anyhow, `read  -r machine || break` is a lot shorter than the three lines you're using to do the same thing). And please `echo "$REPLY"` -- just `echo $REPLY` will replace a `*` in your current data (for example) with a list of filenames.

Comment: Unquoted values in `[ $first -eq 0 ]` isn't safe either unless you know `IFS` -- consider what happens with `IFS=0`. Safer to **always** quote your expansions.

Comment: And please, **please** don't encourage folks to put commands into variables -- [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) results in a class of bugs we see much too much of here.

Comment: Actually -- using `/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash` makes bashisms such as `read` with no variable name into bugs: They'll fail outright if your code was run on Debian or anywhere else `sh` were ash or dash instead of bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy all noted, ty. Actually I started with "read -r REPLY", then shortened for brevity. It's unlikely that IFS=0. I don't encourage to put commands in variables - it is to clarify the filter usage. You are true for bashism. The answer aimed to show concepts, it is not a production script...

Comment: Get used to the whippings from Charles -- and snatch the pebbles of wisdom that accompany them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ok for the wisdom, when it does not get extreme. Otherwise we should drop shell and use some serious language which has not those kind of substitution problems, like intercal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution up to now.

`cat test.txt | awk '/^com-/ {x=$0; matched=flag=1; next} matched {x=x"\n"$0; matched=0; next} $0&&flag {print x; flag=0} !flag {print}'`